# Angular app with undefined observable does not cause ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError Error but it seems like it should?

Tags: angular

ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError makes sense. Angular tracks some state so it can tell when to re-render. If state is changing between renderings this is not desirable.

I have an Angular 8 Stackblitz that throws that error when assigning an observable on AfterViewInit but does render:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/multiple-observable-assigns-mjxvat?file=src/app/app.component.ts

And an Angular 12 example that doesnt throw an error but doesnt render anything:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zduzrq?file=src/app/app.component.ts

What has changed in the framework to alter this behaviour? I cannot find documentation on it.

Comment: This probably isn't an "answer", but the Angular team put a lot of work into improving error messaging in Angular 12 release so they might have gotten rid of that error in that circumstance? Maybe the framework doesn't register another change cycle in the event you're setting observables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior you are observing has nothing to do with any change between different versions of the framework.

The reason for this varying behavior is the ChangeDetectionStrategy being used in both scenarios. In case of Angular 8 example, no ChangeDetectionStrategy is set and hence `Default` strategy is being used; whereas in case of Angular 12 example, you have explicitly set the strategy to `OnPush`.

Comment: I am blind and very silly